# Are smaller or larger pavers better for covering a concrete patio?

Tags: concrete, patio, pavers

I have a large ( 16' x 16' ) thick slab concrete patio that is pouted in 8 x 8 blocks. it has significant spalling and some settling. The concrete is 6" thick and situation in such a way that tearing out the concrete would not be ideal ( not to mention other than the spalling its not in bad shape ). I've considered trying to re-surface or re-pour a layer of concrete over the existing slabs, but now I'm considering just trying to lay concrete pavers over it. I'm wondering ( other than aesthetics ) if there are advantages and disadvantages to using smaller or larger pavers in this application.

Ive considered these two options thus far 
http://low.es/1WD4biM
http://low.es/1WD4fiK

and looking for some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a lot of seasonal movement, it won't matter. I'd layer a small amount of sand as a pad and leveler (plus landscape fabric to control weed growth if you like) and go with whatever looks nice to you.

If things do move a fair bit, smaller pavers will handle it better and be less likely to break over time.

Comment: Any thoughts on the thickness of the sand? is the sand better than fine gravel ? .... also the wood in between the slabs has rotted away, not sure what to fill them with ..... was thinking gravel for drainage

Comment: Sand drains just fine and doesn't have lumps.